# How to convert C/unix integer datetime in seconds since 1970  to DateTime in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, datetime

I know how to use python's time to convert "1328834615" to a date.

```
>>> import time
>>> time.ctime(1328834615)
'Fri Feb 10 08:43:35 2012'
```

How do I do it using Delphi?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try using the [`UnixToDateTime`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/DateUtils.UnixToDateTime) function which is part of the [DateUtils](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/DateUtils) unit.

```
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  DateUtils,
  SysUtils;

Var
  Dt : TDateTime;
begin
  try
    Dt := UnixToDateTime(1328834615);
    //do something
    Writeln(FormatDateTime('ddd mmm d hh:nn:ss yyyy', Dt));

  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
  Readln;
end.
```